# Windows 2003 server restrict file access permission to allow only one user

Tags: windows, permissions, file-access

We have a legacy DOS app running on our Windows 2003 server. It frequently uses one file, and is very sensitive (ie will break) if the file is "touched" by another process. For example, if the file is being scanned by virus-scanning software, or the file is highlighted by mouse click in Windows Explorer.

To make it more stable, I'd like to restrict access to the file using Windows File Permissions. I am going to give access permission to the user starts the DOS app, but to no other users including the SYSTEM account and sys admins.

Will I be able to do it, will my approach work (ie prevent other processes 'touching' the file)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach will work... mostly.  It's not even difficult.  But you may not be able to stop all anti-virus software since most of them use kernel-mode components that can override security settings.  Obviously they must, otherwise malware authors could simply use security settings to prevent their files from being scanned.  Another problem area might be backup utilities, but that's a rare occurrence, usually no more than once per day at most.  I would go ahead and do a quick implementation of your approach and test it with as many anti-virus packages as you can.  I would expect you will eliminate 95% of all problems, but not 100%.

Comment: Thanks Carey. I wonder if I start a Dos app, what account will it run under - the user I logged on with, or the SYSTEM account?

Comment: It will run under the account you started it from.